# Functional components that take prop updates but don't re-render

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Button` component that should submit a form (provided via props) to the server. Before the button is clicked the form is mutated very often, so when *connecting* the `Button` to it, the Button re-renders very oftern as well.

Before hooks, I solved this *problem* by providing a `shouldComponentUpdate` that returns `false` but updates `this.form`, so that the instance variable is always up to date, even if the component is not re-rendering:

```
class ButtonContainer extends React.Component {

  form = null;

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // prevent re-render but update variable
    this.form = nextProps.form;
    return false
  }

  submitForm = () => {
    console.log(this.form);
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.submitForm}>Submit</button>
  }
}
```

Can we achieve the same with functional components?

Comment: Why do you need all form data inside your ButtonContainer? You could just pass callback without excessive data inside ButtonContainer and handle it in the parent component

Answer (score 0):

If you want your component to be updated only when props change, you should use  [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) for functional components. And for class components, it will better to use extending from [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). With `PureComponent` you don't need to implement `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: There is a section on this in the react hook FAQs. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: Thank you. I've added an example above.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are wanting to do without a demo, but you should look into the `useEffect` hook, and namely the second value you can pass to it to decide when it should (re)run https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: Thank you. I've added an example above.

Comment: I get it now, see the `memo` answers below, they are better

Comment: No, I don't think so. `memo` won't help because it will re-render the component everytime, since the `form` prop is changing.

Answer (score 0):

React memo – which is one of React’s top level APIs – can be used for React Function Components to prevent a rerender when the incoming props of this component haven’t changed

For more details please visit here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Here is a example of using `memo` in which the Count component doesn’t update anymore when the user types something into the input field. Only the App component rerenders.

```
import React, { useState, memo } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState('Hello React!');
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleIncrement = () =>
    setCount(currentCount => currentCount + 1);

  const handleDecrement = () =>
    setCount(currentCount => currentCount - 1);

  const handleChange = event => setGreeting(event.target.value);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      <Count count={count} />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleIncrement}>
        Increment
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleDecrement}>
        Decrement
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Count = memo(({ count }) => {
  console.log('Does it (re)render?');
  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I explained my problem badly, so I've edited my question.